# Proper consumption of iterator without using for...of

Tags: javascript, loops, iterator

I'm using [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) which will return an iterator object, but isn't supported in IE. I added a [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params/blob/v0.10.0/build/url-search-params.js), but now IE doesn't have any native support for the returned [iterator object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) as it doesn't implement the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) syntax.

What is the preferred syntax for calling an iterator object without `for..of`?

Here's the ES6 `for...of` syntax:

```js
var paramsString = "Name=Fiona&Type=Hippo";
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
var entries = urlParams.entries();

for(pair of entries) { 
  console.log(pair[0], pair[1]); 
}
```

```js
var paramsString = "Name=Fiona&Type=Hippo";
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
var entries = urlParams.entries();

for(pair of entries) { 
  console.log(pair[0] + ": " + pair[1]); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/WebReflection/url-search-params/v0.10.0/build/url-search-params.js"></script>
```

I'd love to find a canonical source that implements the calling syntax for iterator objects back to older browsers without relying on transpiling `for...of`.

Comment: https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-equivalents-in-es5#iterators-and-for-of - is it looking like the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not good old `forEach` ?

a `console.log(urlParams);` shows that the object returned has the `forEach` method but surprisingly it's not mentioned among the methods in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```
urlParams.forEach(function(value, key){ 
    console.log(key + ' : ' + value)
});
```

```js
var paramsString = "Name=Fiona&Type=Hippo";
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

urlParams.forEach(function(value, key){ 
  console.log(key + ' : ' + value)
});
```

#### Proto Methods of `UrlSearchParams` in each browser:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you are nervous about `while(true)`,you can try this:

```js
var paramsString = "Name=Fiona&Type=Hippo";
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
var entries = urlParams.entries();
var iterator = entries.next();
while(!iterator.done) {  
  if (iterator.value) {
console.log(iterator.value[0] + ": " +
            iterator.value[1])
  }
  iterator=entries.next();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/WebReflection/url-search-params/v0.10.0/build/url-search-params.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your constraints are, but you could also use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) on your `entries` variable, if that's available to you.

```
var paramsString = "Name=Fiona&Type=Hippo";
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
var entries = [...urlParams.entries()]; // Use spread operator here

// Now entries is just an array with all the normal array methods on it.
entries.forEach(pair => console.log(pair[0], pair[1]));
```

Comment: Cool idea, although it's likely the case that the same instances where [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) isn't supported also won't support other ES6 operators like [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) so you're transpiling either way.  Here's the [browser compatibility tables for both operators](https://i.imgur.com/VuKAd8t.png) and IE isn't supported in either case.  Although a cool potential use case for spread.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at an iterator implementation, but the `while(true)` makes me nervous.  Any other sources / implementations welcome.

```js
var paramsString = "Name=Fiona&Type=Hippo";
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
var entries = urlParams.entries();

while(true) {
  var iterator = entries.next()
  if (iterator.value) {
    console.log(iterator.value[0] + ": " +
                iterator.value[1])
  }
  if (iterator.done) {
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/WebReflection/url-search-params/v0.10.0/build/url-search-params.js"></script>
```

Comment: The code is misleading, as it actually loops 3 times.`iterator.done` turns to `true` the next time _after_ the last element.
It only does not print the third time because of `if (iterator.value)`. But when a iterator contains values like null,undefined,0,false, this would also not be printed. The `if (iterator.done)` should be right after `entries.next()` and `if (iterator.value)` is not necessary